# How do I change the overall theme of a tkinter application?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4, tkinter.style

I want to change the theme of my tkinter application to clam.

What is the code and  where do I put it? I have tried:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
s=ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
```

Comment: Use [tkinter.ttk](http://www.tkinter.ttk) to get the the themed version of Tk.

Comment: thanks, how do i change to clam, default, ect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**To change the theme, call `.theme_use()` with the theme's name as the argument.**

From https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-theme-layer.html

> A number of operations related to themes require that you have
>   available an instance of the `ttk.Style()` class (in the Python sense of
>   class). For example, to obtain a list of the available themes in your
>   installation:
>
> ```
> >>> import ttk  # import tkinter.ttk as ttk for Python 3
> >>> s=ttk.Style()
> >>> s.theme_names()
> ('clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic')
> ```
>
> The `.theme_names()` method returns a tuple containing the names of the
>   available styles. The '`classic`' theme gives you the original, pre-ttk
>   appearance.
>
> To determine which theme you get by default, use the `.theme_use()`
>   method with no arguments. To change the current theme, call this same
>   method with the desired theme name as the argument:
>
> ```
> >>> s.theme_use()
> 'default'
> >>> s.theme_use('alt')
> >>> s.theme_use()
> 'alt'
> ```

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'ttk'.

Comment: Sorry, Python 3: `import tkinter.ttk as ttk`

Answer (score 4):

This post is pretty outdated, here is how you can easily set the theme in Python3 with **just one** line of code:

Add this below your "Tk()" line. For example:

```
window = Tk() # <--- Main window line

ttk.Style().theme_use('default') # <--- Change default to whichever theme you want to use.
```

Where 'default' is the name of the default theme. Change 'default' to any of the available themes that you like.

**Here is a good list of themes with screenshots:**

<-- *Current themes as of 2020* -->

https://ttkthemes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/themes.html

Some themes from the list above are not included in the main tkinter download.

If this is the case, you can easily install the theme files that aren't included in the default ttk install by running this command:

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkthemes
```

Hope this helped you!

Comment: `ttk.Style().theme_use('default')` cannot be used with `ttkthemes` themes? please tell how to use it with `ttkthemes`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from tkinter import ttk

>>> s=ttk.Style()

>>> s.theme_names() """======== if you are under win 8.1 you must see ..
 ('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative') you can use for example 'clam' ===== """

>>> s.theme_use('clam')
```