# how to make modern button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have abutton like this in tkinter (Modern window 10 buttons):
[image: button_i_want]

However, I get this button:
[image: my_button]

The code for my button is:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button
root=Tk()
Button(root,text='OK').pack()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the overall theme of a tkinter application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367710/how-do-i-change-the-overall-theme-of-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: try `from tkinter import ttk as ttk` and use this `butt = ttk.Button(root)`

Comment: You can use themes like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63325559/how-to-set-a-style-to-my-whole-tkinter-app/63326642#63326642) and make a button with the theme.

Answer (score 1):

The themed widgets are in 'themed Tk' aka ttk.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
ok = ttk.Button(root, text='OK')
ok.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Avoid `from tkinter import *` as both tkinter and tkinter.ttk define Button and many other widgets.

If you use this on Windows you should get something looking like a native button. But this is a theme and can be changed. On Linux or MacOS you will get a button style that is appropriate to that platform.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to create button is to create a label and bind it to the action functions. In the below example `.bind()` is used to connect the label with respective function. You can design according to your requirements.

```
from tkinter import *

def OnPressed(event):
    print('Hello')
def OnHover(event):
    But.config(bg='red', fg='white')
def OnLeave(event):
    But.config(bg='white', fg='black')

root = Tk()

But = Label(root, text='Hi', bg='white', relief='groove')
But.place(x=10, y=10, width=100)
But.bind('<Button-1>', OnPressed)
But.bind('<Enter>', OnHover)
But.bind('<Leave>', OnLeave)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this answer is completely off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
vol_up = Button(root, text="+",activebackground='orange',bg='yellow')
vol_up.pack(side='top')
```

Comment: set height and width respectively

Comment: What is this code for